# What happens when a user holds the headset button

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to find out what happens when a user pushes the media button of headset. I know the phone recognizes holding the button, but when I test it myself and hold the button broadcast will send a `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`. When I push the button down and release it, I get two broadcasts (one for `ACTION_DOWN` and one for `ACTION_UP`). But when I hold it doesn't send anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is how most buttons work for anything. Almost no hardware will tell you when something is being pushed down, just when a change is made.

If you want to know how long a button is held down for, you want to start recording the time using something like `System.currentTimeMillis` when you receive an `ACTION_DOWN` message and when you receive an `ACTION_UP` you can record the end time and then calculate the difference.

Comment: the problem is when the button hold down I even don't get ACTION_DOWN but when it just press without holding everything is ok